# Get the nodes with specific labels in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all the nodes that have specific labels. My code:

```
match (n) where labels(n)=["Person","Actor","Old"] return n
```

While there are nodes that satisfy this property I do not get any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List does not match if the items are not in the same order/sequence. So first of all, list out all labels in your database so you can see how the labels are arranged.

```
match (n) 
return distinct labels(n)
```

Then you will see which node will have those labels that you look for:  ["Person","Actor","Old"].

If you are trying to find nodes where it contains all nodes in that list in any order then this query will work for you.

```
match (n) 
where all(lbl in ["Person","Actor","Old"] where lbl in labels(n))
return n
```

if you like using APOC functions, here is the query

```
match (n)
where apoc.coll.isEqualCollection(["Person","Actor","Old"], labels(n))
return n
```

Comment: The apoc function is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

This is why:

Labels(n) returns an array of strings, but not necessarily in a specific order.

You can try this:

```
WHERE n:Person AND n:Actor AND n:Old
```

Or

```
WHERE ALL(l in [“Person”, “Actor”, “Old”] WHERE l IN labels(n) )
```